# Difference between package simulating module, and real module

Tags: python, module, package

Lets assume we write some component, which will be distributed. Lets call it "worker". Worker should do some magic, but API is quite simple - 2 or 3 classes/functions. BUT insides of worker are quite big. We need non-API functions.

End-user should be using it like this:

```
from worker import foo
...
foo(x)
```

or

```
import worker
...
worker.foo(x)
```

But foo uses "login" which takes lot of bit operations, hashing, encoding, etc, and "calculate" which uses hell lot of math expressions.

So, now we have 2 options for code organisation:

1. Only one module, called "worker" which will have API functions ("foo"), internal functions ("login", "calculate") and `__all__` variable with value `["foo", ...]`.
2. We create package "worker", and split logic into submodules:

   ```
   worker
   worker/__init__.py
   worker/api.py
   worker/login_related.py
   worker/calculate_related.py
   ```

   and in `__init__.py` we put:

   ```
   from worker.api import *
   ```

Now user shouldn't be able to tell if "worker" is module or package.

But is he?

I know, that `worker.__file__` will return path with `__init__.py` at the end. Also, qualified names of API functions will point to modules, not to package (unless I define them in `__init__.py`). What are other differences? How can one differentiate between "masked package" and module?

Comment: Does it matter at all? Why do you need to distinguish between the two types? `unittest` in the stdlib is a package, but I bet you didn't know that or cared.

Comment: Yeah, it kinda matters. For example: __file__ behaviour means that some directory-related magic can be tricky. I'd like to know what else is different, so I may avoid it or find a workaround, when I need that (while creating some code-analysing tool, etc).

Comment: Right, for a code analysis tool, it's all still just modules. They still have `__file__` attributes. Directory-related magic isn't tricky here, you still have a proper path. Python 3.3 introduces namespaces, those are perhaps more tricky (no `__file__` attribute, because there is no module). See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/. Namespaces have a `__path__` attribute.

Comment: Ok, that is something I will totally read. But still, question is unanswered, and we're having discussion on "why did you ask this question". I'd say it's not the point here.

Comment: You answered the second question yourself. The first question seems unclear - seems that you've verified already all possible properties of modules created in other way. Questions "did I miss anything" are generally too broad/unclear. This is somehow a specific case, and well specified though, so I'm not voting to close, but I have mixed feelings :)